# How to access child element of API response in Angular/Typescript?

Tags: angular, typescript

I´ve a **REST API** that returns json data in the **following structure** - the content itself is **inside a "data" node**, cause sometimes there will be additional meta information in the request (e.g. for pagination).

```
{
    "data": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "title": "List 1"
        },
        {
            "id": 2,
            "title": "List 2"
        },
    ]
}
```

I fetch the data with the Angular http Client as follows:

```
getLists (): Observable<List[]> {
  return this._httpClient.get<List[]>('http://localhost/api/v1/lists').pipe(
    tap((response) => {
      this._lists.next(response)
    }),
  )
}
```

The issue - as you may already - is, that the **response is not an array of elements of type "List"**, cause the **elements are inside the "data" node**. Accessing the content inside the data node on the response object will also not work, cause of the set generic / expected return type.

Is there a way to **keep using the generic** on the get() method and **access the content inside the "data" array**, so that it ends up in an array of List objects?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The closest thing possible (assuming you want to use the generic) is to define a `Response` type, like this:

```js
interface Response {
  data: List[]
}
```

and then you can change the HTTP client to use Response instead, and add a `map` stage, so you can get the data:

```js
getLists (): Observable<List[]> {
  return this._httpClient.get<Response>('http://localhost/api/v1/lists').pipe(
    map(item => item.data),
    tap((response) => {
      this._lists.next(response)
    })
  )
}
```